# Superfish main menu children are breaking on certain pages

Tags: javascript, css, superfish

### Preface

I have a (Superfish JS) horizontal main menu in my Drupal 7.38 site. Some of it's links being opened for sub menus, and These sub menus contains the children of the parent links.

This menu appears in the header section of the site, and in all pages.

### The problem

When I surf from Mozilla firefox 39.0 and visit my home page, the triggered sub-menu appears to break, but when I surf that way in another page of the menu, it doesn't break...

[Here is a live example](http://www.benia.biz).

[image]

### My final aim

1. A plausible way to determine if the problem is JS or CSS based.
2. A detailed suggestion for a solution (especially if it's JS based since I'm just starting to learn JS and I almost know nothing about it).

Would affirm & rate if working. Thank you!

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce in Firefox 39 (Mac OS X). Any more specific instructions for reproducing?

Comment: I use win7 home premium... I've cleared Drupal cache, Firefox 39.0 cache, and clicked ctrl+f5 and the problem persists... though it doesn't happen in Chrome or IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some mysterious reason, after clearing Drupal cache, and rightafterwords - Cloudflare cache, the problem seem to no longer occur.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal caching does cause random breaking of Superfish menus. You will need to look at the Drupal Watchlog for the javascript warning and errors. Please post these warnings/errors in the post here so solution can be proposed.

Flushing the cache (specifically registry) resolves the issue.

As a workout solution I suggest to downgrade your JQUERY library to version 1.8.

Please go through the [Drupal Link](https://www.drupal.org/node/2236571) for more information.